# Is Carl Jung synchronicity scientific theory?

Tags: jung

Do you know about **synchronicity theory** (Carl Jung) and what scientific work has been done and is it proven? (what common references)

Is it possible that it could be related to the **collective subconscious** if it is real? (Scientific  common references)

Thanks.

Comment: I think is very true theory. I am a example of that "problem", but you need to understand that synchronicity happens in some "point" that is the "union Point" of many things that "are not connected to each other", when we dive into each one. What humanity is by the way, if not bodies who manipulate and process information? Glad any definition of any text is always flexible to each one interpretation. Hi, I am the Brain Snail. Children always love that style of saying what is always (even in the scientific articles) flexible to each one interpretation. At least they normally accept without ques

Answer (score 4):

Synchronicity is an interesting philosophical idea; unfortunately there is no evidence that it actually exists.  Therefore, there are some people who consider Jung's theory to be pseudoscientific.

> Robert Todd Carroll, in his book "The Skeptics Dictionary," notes that "even if there were a synchronicity between the mind and the world such that certain coincidences resonate with transcendental truth, there would still be the problem of figuring out those truths. What guide could one possibly use to determine the correctness of an interpretation?" There is no scientific or objective way to determine whether synchronicity is valid or not; it's all subjective personal opinion and experience and flexible definitions.

You can read more on this on [this LiveScience webpage](https://www.livescience.com/43105-synchronicity-definition-meaning.html)

I also commented on synchronicity within an [article I wrote in May](https://www.whatstheproblem.co.uk/pseudoscience-in-psychology/)

> Many of Jung’s theories are considered to be pseudoscience. One example is synchronicity, his idea that meaningful connections in the world manifest through coincidence with no apparent causal link. This is what Jung referred to as the acausal connecting principle ([Nickell, 2002](https://skepticalinquirer.org/newsletter/visitations_after-death_contacts/?/sb/show/visitations_after-death_contacts)). This is because these ideas culminated from his ideas about the paranormal. Despite his own experiments failing to confirm the phenomenon (Shermer & Linse, 2002) he held on to the idea as an explanation for apparent ESP (Jung, 2013).

### References

Jung, C. G. (2013). Synchronicity: An Acausal Connecting Principle. London: Routledge.

Nickell, J. (2002). “Visitations”: After-Death Contacts. Skeptical Inquirer 12(3) Retrieved from https://skepticalinquirer.org/newsletter/visitations_after-death_contacts/?/sb/show/visitations_after-death_contacts

Shermer, M. & Linse, P. (2002). The skeptic encyclopedia of pseudoscience (Vol. 1). Santa Barbara, CA: ABC-CLIO.

Comment: I have a question  in your opinion can be asked in this forum for getting more information about that ?  and it is about  What would be the consequences of proving the synchronicity for humans, for example based on quantum Entanglement theory, jung  and some peoples sequence evidence which happens more than random , is it could be useful for human treating or could be used to creating one more powerful humans for controlling via theirs environment not  morally? what do you think?